# Deleting a record in a file in Java

Tags: java, file

```
public class Client {
    private Scanner scanner;
    private String fileClient="client.txt";
    public File client =new File(fileClient);
    

public void deletClient() {
            int lineRemove =GetLineRemove();
            String tempFile="temp.txt";
            File newfile=new File(tempFile);
            int line=0;
            String currentLine;
            
            
            try {
                FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(tempFile,true);
                BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(fw);
                PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(bw);
                
                FileReader fr=new FileReader(fileClient);
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
                
                while((currentLine=br.readLine())!=null ) {
                    line++;
                    
                    if(line !=lineRemove) {
                        pw.println(currentLine);
                    }
                }
                pw.flush();
                fr.close();
                bw.close();
                pw.close();
                br.close();
                fw.close();
             // i try to delet a file
                client.delete();
                        // create a file have the same name 
                File dumy=new File(fileClient);
                      // rename it to first file 
                newfile.renameTo(dumy);
                
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.print(e);
            }
            
        }
```

I want to remove a line from a file but when i do that i found the first file still exist and the second file what should get rename to the first file still have has it name temp  i don't know should do so i hope u can help me to know where is the problem.

Comment: i just run it and it work as you said it rename the new file back to the old one do you get any exception ? for this line client.delete(); could your check it's boolan return if it return true or false

Comment: it was return false

Comment: the only thing i can think of is the permission of file so right click the file and see if your current account has write permission for it

Comment: i don't know how i can do this or could u be more clear sir

Comment: it different based on your operating system so try to google how to check file permission for your operating system and you will get many pages on how  to do that

Comment: for example this https://www.microcenter.com/tech_center/article/10900/how-to-check-or-change-file-permissions-in-windows-10 show you the steps for windows 10 use steps from 1 to 5 if you have different os let me know and i search it for you